# choosing a striping number for lvcreate

Tags: lvm

I have a storage unit that holds 84 SAS SSD's.  It has two [scsi] controllers that connect the disk storage unit to a linux host server.  Currently the *automated* storage setup created a *virtual* (as opposed to *linear*) storage array having two disk pools each of 42 disks, and then a volume is created on each of them.  The two volumes show up as `/dev/sdb` and `/dev/sdc`.  I `vgcreate` and `lvcreate` on those two block devices.

my question is what stripe number should be used for optimal performance based on what I have described?  Should it be 2 because of 2 controllers?  Or 84 because there is 84 total disks?  Or some other number?

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you have two disk arrays visible from OS point of view as `sdb` and `sdc`. And you add them in LVM. So you should tell LVM you have 2 stripes.

But I would like to warn you about the arrays on controllers. You do not mention what kind of RAID you use but 42 disks are too much. I personally will make (per controller) arrays with maximum of 12-14 disks and will make them RAID6 with spare disk for each array.

Comment: `sda` is my rhel-7.9 disk, `sdb` & `sdc` show up as the volumes from the storage unit, which is a Dell powervault.  If I choose *linear* storage then I have to do multiple RAID pools each limited to 16, but the recommended is a *virtual* storage type that has a maximum of 128 disks per pool and the *make the choices for me automated recommended setup* did it

Comment: It did mention *linear* storage setup is more for performance, but the technical description of all that was, not very detailed.

Comment: @ron, edited about disks. Unfortunately I have no experience with this controller. And again - so much disks in one chunk looks very unreliable for me.

Comment: i'm contacting dell about it and all the technicalities, wanted to get a simple high level understanding of LVM striping.  I suspect the powervault has some designed in feature to mitigate what you describe.  thanks.